# write to csv file gets cut when writing using file.writeallbytes

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a CSV file and storing it in object. 
I then write the object into a file using bytes

```
File.WriteAllBytes("some.csv",ObjectToByteArray(items));

private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
     {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);


            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            return encoding.GetBytes(ms.ToString());



        }
```

The file doesnt get written completely and it gets cut. I sense this is due to stream size restrictions.

How to ensure the entire file is being written correctly. When I use CSVwriter it still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Is your original CSV file ASCII formatted file ? if you are not sure, try to resave it (even with notepad) like ASCII file, there is a combo where you can choose format to save in SaveAs dialog, and see what happens.

Comment: I read a csv file and store it into an object. I serialized the object after processing and write it back to into a file.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to read a CSV file and storing it in object.?

Comment: Can you post sample of the result of File.WriteAllBytes("some.csv",ObjectToByteArray(items));

Comment: TextReader reader = File.OpenText("xxxx.csv");           
            var parser = new CsvParser(reader);
                       
           while (true)
            {
                var row = parser.Read();
                if (row == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                 // do some manipulation here and store it.
                 
                });
                }
            }